# Asynchronous block call to self crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking

I have an API call (using AFNetworking) that when fails calls a failure block. This block simply stop the table view refresh controller via 'self.refreshController.stopRefreshing();
However at run-time this causes a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

```
failure: { (error: NSError!, reason: String!) -> Void in
                self.refreshController.endRefreshing()
        }
```

I've tried putting the call in a 'dispatch_async' main queue but the call is already on the Main queue and the same error arises.

```
failure: { (error: NSError!, reason: String!) -> Void in
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
                {
                    self.refreshController.endRefreshing()
                }
        }
```

This leads me to believe the issue is to do with a pointer to 'self' at the time the failure block is called... I've tried 'weak' and 'unowned' self but these don't resolve it.

```
failure: { [weak self] (error: NSError!, reason: String!) -> Void in
                self?.refreshController.endRefreshing()
        }
```

Any thoughts would be welcome.

**UPDATE:** Initialisaton

```
class ResultsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewControllerDelegate, UITableViewControllerDataSource 
{ 
    var refreshController = UIRefreshControl() 

    override func viewDidLoad() 
    { 
        super.viewDidLoad() 
        // pull-to-refresh setup                  
        self.refreshController.addTarget(self, action: "refreshTable:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged) 
        self.tableView.addSubview(self.refreshController) 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `self` at the point of the crash? What is the value of `self.activityIndicator`?

Comment: Apologies, code should be 'refreshController' (there is also an activity indicator but I figured once this was resolved it would be same issue). To answer your question: 

The debugger states:

self ViewController 0xfffffffffffffc0d 0xfffffffffffffc0d
refreshController UIRefreshControl  

Does that help or did I gather the wrong info?

Comment: println(self) causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1 address=0x20)

Comment: can you show the code where you initialise the UIRefreshControl

Comment: var refreshController = UIRefreshControl() as a class instance in a UIViewController

Comment: Where are you initializing the refreshController?

Comment: `class ResultsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewControllerDelegate, UITableViewControllerDataSource {
     var refreshController = UIRefreshControl()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // pull-to-refresh setup
        self.refreshController.addTarget(self, action: "refreshTable:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        self.tableView.addSubview(self.refreshController)
    }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually found the root cause.

I was using AFNetworking for API calls and had created a custom Failure block which included the reason if the API call failed. This was up the chain in the call stack but this error seemed to mask it. None of the above methods were required, but using the weak self method did help the compiler surface the issue in the right file.

The issue could be traced back to the here:

**Two block type aliases**

```
typealias SuccessBlock = (responseArray: AnyObject!) -> Void
typealias FailureBlock = (error: NSError, reason: String) -> Void
```

**AFNetworking POST call**

```
private func post(url: String, inout parameters: [String : AnyObject], success: SuccessBlock, failure: FailureBlock)
{
    self.sessionManager.POST(url,
        parameters: parameters,
        success: { (operation: NSURLSessionDataTask!, responseObject: AnyObject!) -> Void in
            println("DEBUG: API POST Request to \(url) successful.")
            var responses = responseObject as? [AnyObject]
            success(responseArray:responses)
        },
        failure: { (operation: NSURLSessionDataTask!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            let reason = self.getResponseReasonFromError(error)
            println("DEBUG: API GET Request to \(url) \nFailed: \(error). \nAPI Response: \(reason)")
            failure(error: error, reason: reason)
        }
    )
}
```

**Error was here in the FailureBlock type alias**

```
typealias FailureBlock = (error: NSError, reason: String) -> Void
typealias FailureBlock = (error: NSError, reason: String!) -> Void
```

Missing a ! after String.

Comment: Nice find. Such a weird way to crash. Mine was crashing right at the end of the completion handler in swift. This really saved me a lot of messing around! I was missing a ? in a handler somewhere. cheers